# export class rule

Tags: c++

recently i have been wondering why we can use mfc's class while it seems not to export its classes,    cause i know we can export a class using  __declspec(dllimport),for example:
i define a class CBaseClass in a dll named test.dll,then i use it as a base class in my test.exe;before i can use CBaseClass i should first export it from test.dll;so i think that ruld should apply to mfc;but i don't see that anywhere in mfc's source code ,anyboy can shed a light on this ,thanks

```
class CWnd:public CCmdTarget
{
}
```

there is no __declspec(dllimport),they why can we use it in our project

Comment: Please consider breaking your question down into sentences of manageable length. It is quite difficult to read as is.

Comment: This is a [run-on sentence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-on_sentence) and is not easy to read.  Please fix this.

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to export from a DLL. 
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: but you can't export a class in .def